# How can i dynamic this menu using wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

How to add a custom menu to my WordPress theme.I know how to register nav_menu.Actually, i want to know about the drop-down menu.

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
               <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good article [here](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/wordpress-3-drop-down-menu-tutorial/) about creating your own custom walker menu class so you can add whatever classes you want to the menu hierarchy.

```
class CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker extends Walker {

  var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';        
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
      unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

Then to show your menu in a header.php template use the following.

```
<?php  
wp_nav_menu(array(  
  'menu' => 'Main Navigation', 
  'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
  'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker()
)); 
?>
```